# Passing R matrix to a low-level .C function, accessing the array to change its values

Tags: c, arrays, r, matrix

I'm exploring the basic `.C` call -- for a C standard experience -- passing a R matrix to a C function, using it as a (bi-dims) C array. Working on (1-dim) vectors I don't have any problem, but in this case I receive a core dump. How can I access every single cell of my array and change its values? Is it the right approach?

My R matrix:

```
> x <- matrix((1:100), ncol=10, nrow=10)
> x
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

This is the R function:

```
testr <- function(x) {
  d <- as.integer(dim(x))
  r <- .C("testc",
        d,
        x <- as.integer(x))
  return(r[[2]])
}
```

And this is the relative C function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void testc(int *dim, int *x) {
  int i, j;

  for (j = 0; j < dim[0]; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < dim[1]; i++) {
      x[j][i] = pow(x[j][i], 2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks strange, your C definition is wrong or at least the usage of it.
x is a one dimensional array not a 2 dimensional (according to the definition of testc). Btw `<-` looks like meaning Assign this. Then, your function return nothing so ( if I understand correctly ) `r <-` can't be done.

Comment: tried with `void testc(int *dim, int **x)`. Same result.

Comment: A running hack is handling the matrix as a 1-dim numeric vector, restoring the 2-dim matrix in the R function (with `matrix(r[[2]], ncol=d[1], nrow=d[2])`). But it's not the answer to my question.

Comment: `as.integer(x)` loses the "dim" attribute of `x`, so even if R _did_ store matrices as 2-d C arrays, `x[j][i]` would not be valid. You could replace `as.integer` with `storage.mode(x) = "integer"` to ensure correct input. Besides that, if you want o simply access each element of `x` you could use something like `for(int i = 0; i < (dim[0] * dim[1]); i++) x[i] = pow(x[i], 2);`, else, if you need the dimensions to your computation, you could loop with an offset like `int nr = dim[0], nc = dim[1]; for(int i = 0; i < nr; i++) for(int j = 0; j < nc; j++) x[i + j*nr] = pow(x[i + j*nr], 2);`

Comment: Thank you alexis_laz. It's now clear to me why I didn't find any document about that thread. The "limits" of `.C()` are obvious, and probably it is still there for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

The comment by Alexis Laz is spot on: the `.C()` interfaces **forces** the conversion of what in R is a matrix (in essence: a vector plus dimension attributes) down to just the vector without dimension.

That is one of many reasons why the recommendation these days is to use `.Call()` with its richer interface using `SEXP` objects.  And if you use Rcpp you don't even have to anything:

```
R> cppFunction("NumericMatrix doubleMe(NumericMatrix M) { return 2*M; }")
R> doubleMe(matrix(1:9, 3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    8   14
[2,]    4   10   16
[3,]    6   12   18
R>
```

This just defined an Rcpp one-liner to take a matrix and return twice its value.

Comment: Thank you Dirk, I already know your good work on Rcpp, but I'm exploring the different available ways to write low-level functions or extensions. I already read how `.Call()` could be a better option, but I need to learn how to access a bi-dim array with `.C()`. The only example I found is the `floyd.c` (e1071), but I can't understand how they used their refs.

Comment: I don't know how words you need for this but it boils to _`.C()` is bad for you and your question demonstrated one reason why_.  Feel free to continue t o use it but it _will create extra work and headaches for you_.